# Jinn comes to me while I'm sleeping!

Tags: jinn

As-salamu `alaykum. During the night, when I am sleeping, I get this strange sensation that almost paralyses my whole body and prevents me waking up. The worst thing is that during that time, I think something is having sexual intercourse with me. I would like to ask if it is Satan causing this to happen, and if so, how can I fight against this bad thing?

Comment: read ayat kursi before going to sleep (and when feeling as you describe too, even purely "in your mind")... see for example: http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=13513

Comment: Does this happen to you in a particular room or particular bed? What if you sleep in different room or different place? Does it still happen?

Comment: you should clear your bed first before going sleep..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us to diagnose a condition that we as a site are in no way qualified to handle (see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/853/22); you would be far better off asking a trusted professional than random strangers on the Internet.

Answer (score 10):

This problem is called "**Sleep Paralysis**" and has some scientific causes and treatments.
You can read about them [**here**](http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/guide/sleep-paralysis). For example, there's said that:

> Up to as many as four out of every 10 people may have sleep paralysis.
>   This common condition is often first noticed in the teen years. But
>   men and women of any age can have it. Sleep paralysis may run in
>   families. Other factors that may be linked to sleep paralysis include:
>
> - Lack of sleep
> - Sleep schedule that changes
> - Mental conditions such as stress or bipolar disorder
> - Sleeping on the back
> - Other sleep problems such as narcolepsy or nighttime leg cramps
> - Use of certain medications
> - Substance abuse

Doubtlessly, reciting Quran before sleep (especially [Ayat al Kursi](http://quran.com/2/255-257)) and getting to sleep with the remembrance of Allah will complement these treatments.

Answer (score -1):

Walaikumsalam,

This is not "Sleep Paralysis" as the previous answer has been stated. It is clearly the problem of a Jinn.

The most important thing to get rid of the Jinn is start getting closer to your Creator Allah (s) through His obedience and getting rid of sins.

Always stay in wudhu. And before Sleeping recite Surah Ikhlas, Falaq & Nas three times, Ayatal-Kursi and blow it on your hands and rub it on your whole body.

You may need to visit a rakhi to solve your problem. And remember a Rakhi will never ask your mother's name and if someone does then he is a Magician.

Comment: -1 
"This is not "Sleep Paralysis" as the previous answer has been stated. It is clearly the problem of a Jinn. "
- What makes you so certain?